# Is it okay to use and distribute python pip package that went private by the creator?

Tags: python, pip

Is it okay to use and distribute python pip package that went private by the creator?

I had a pip package that I have been extensively using via google Colaboratory (meaning never downloaded the package locally), and suddenly the author deleted the github account along with pip packages.

I have never faced this issue before and am deeply worried since the package was essential for the project I have been working on.

What are the common practice when this type of issue arise? I believe some people have downloaded the package to their local machine and could still use it. Is this okay? If so, is it okay for me to find and ask people to share the package with me?

It is a package called clusterensembles https://pypi.org/project/clusterensembles/.

I tried to contact the creator but I have not gotten any response yet.

Could anyone advise me what would be the best solution?

Comment: I don't know if you have already checked. Maybe this is similar to your package? https://github.com/GGiecold/Cluster-Ensembles `pip install Cluster_Ensembles`

Do you have access to the License it used? Can you remember the original repo name?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes I checked the repo you recommended but my code is dependent of some of the features from the other one I mentioned. It was under MIT license, and following is the repo name and cached result of readme. https://github.com/tsano430/ClusterEnsembles  https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:NGBp6Sqp-l4J:https://github.com/tsano430/ClusterEnsembles/blob/main/README.md+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

Comment: @gontxomde [archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20210425071609/https://pypi.org/project/clusterensembles/)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about licensing, not programming.

Comment: I'm no expert, but I think a license of that software doesn't suffice if the software author didn't have the right to grant that license (e.g., because they used algorithms they didn't have the right to (might be the reason they deleted it)).